# best way of converting letters to base-10

Tags: c#

So far I have something such as:

```
if( Char.IsDigit( c ) ) 
   return Int32.Parse( "" + c );

if( Char.IsLetter( c ) ) 
   return Char.ToUpper( c ) - 'A' + 1;
```

Comment: Do you mean: a->1, b->2, c->3 ... z->26?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one:

```
if (Char.IsDigit(c))
    return c - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly detailed [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326742(VS.71).aspx) which is just what you're looking for.